# Network errors while creating a new play application

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to create a new play application and I'm getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

I'm also getting it while trying to update dependencies.

My network connection is just fine. I'm able to browse, however my feeling is that every time I run an activator / play command, I get network error.

Is there any settings which can effect this? Proxy settings? Maybe something in the Java level?

Here's an example of my errors:

```
D:\Git_Work\RSVP>activator ui
Checking for a newer version of Activator (current version 1.3.4)...
   ... failed to get latest version information: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Found previous process id: 6464
Local repository: activator-launcher-local @ file:////D:/Program%20Files/PlayFramework/activator-1.3.5-minimal/repository
Local repository: activator-local @ file:////D:/Java/typesafe-activator-1.3.4/activator-1.3.4/repository
Play server process ID is 6900
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /127.0.0.1:8888
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[info] application - Failed to record a clone of 'play-java-intro-preview': java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I'll appreciate your help!

Comment: Could it be an older Play process is still running in your system? The line `Found previous process id: 6464` in your log suggests this. Maybe try to kill this process or restart your system!?

Comment: tried to restart but without success.. BTW - that's the first time I've installed play on this machine.